# multiple ways of handling update response of array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list of user, after update I handle it this way

```
handleUserUpdated = (user) => {
  let users = this.state.users.slice();
  for (let i = 0, n = users.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (users[i]._id === user._id) {
      users[i].title = user.title;
      users[i].artist = user.artist;
      users[i].published_date = user.published_date;
      break; // Stop this loop, we found it!
    }
  }
  this.setState({ users: users });
}
```

I found flaw in this kind of approach, I have to always declare the properties and using break make me feel the code above is ugly. Any better approach?

not sure this is correct or not.

```
this.setState({ users: users.map(o => o.id === user.id ? Object.assign({}, user, {...user}) : o ) })
```

Comment: Please explain what is purpose of `handleUserUpdated` function ?

Comment: @HassanImam its param (user) is the updated object returned from the db.

Comment: Where are using param ?

Comment: @HassanImam `handleUserUpdated ` has an argument (param) which is user.

Comment: Basically, you are passing a user and checking if it there is a `id` of passed `user` in your `users` state. But, I am not sure what needs to be done when `id` is there and when it's not present?

Comment: @HassanImam you can read below's answer to understand what I'm trying to do. If the id is not present just don't do anything, return the existing users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158434/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-jenny-mok).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more concise way to do it would be:

```
users.map(o => o.id === user.id
  ? {...o, ...user}
  : o
)
```

The biggest problem is that you don't he a ton of control over what you are putting in there... the original may have properties you no longer want that don't get overwritten.

You might consider doing something like:

```
const index = users.findIndex(o => o.id == user.id)
const newUsers = Object.assign([], users, {[index]: user});
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/EbgJBj?editors=0111)

Or

```
const index = users.findIndex(o => o.id == user.id)
const newUsers = [
  ...users.slice(0, index),
  user,
  ...users.slice(index + 1)
]
```

Comment: something is not right with my object.assign attempt? I like the first example, it's clean.

Comment: I had a typeo in the second line `{[index]: newUser}` => `{[index]: user}`.  Requires that you have ES6 support, or transpile, at least.  Here is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/EbgJBj?editors=0111